# css border style for treeview using bootstrap list-group-item

Tags: html, css, treeview, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a `treeview` using `bootstrap` style. which I wrote it myself..but I have problems with the style..I used `list-group` class for `ul` element and `list-group-item` for `li` element but my tree looks like below..how can I solve the border problem for child node and the whole with ??

[image]

which should be like this

[image]

Comment: Can u please provide a working example on JSFiddle? :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```css
body{padding: 1em;}


.list-group-item ul{
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}
.list-group-item li{
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 3em;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.list-group-item li:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    Dapibus ac facilisis in
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li>Cras justo odio</li>
      <li>Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
      <li>
        Morbi leo risus
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>Cras justo odio</li>
          <li>Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis inDapibus ac facilisis in</li>
          <li>Morbi leo risus</li>
          <li>Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
          <li>Vestibulum at eros</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
      <li>Vestibulum at eros</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is the `class="list-unstyled"`  ?

Answer (score 0):

to make a tree view with bootstrap or using

.
to do this you will have to use html css & js as well.
here is the reference that will help you make it possible.

i find this link is useful to you

[bootstrap tree view](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-30-treeview)

[jsfiddel for making awesome treeview](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/)

```js
'Collapse this branch');
    $('.tree li.parent_li > span').on('click', function (e) {
        var children = $(this).parent('li.parent_li').find(' > ul > li');
        if (children.is(":visible")) {
            children.hide('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Expand this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-plus-sign').removeClass('icon-minus-sign');
        } else {
            children.show('fast');
            $(this).attr('title', 'Collapse this branch').find(' > i').addClass('icon-minus-sign').removeClass('icon-plus-sign');
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

i hope you will learn what you want to.